# Nearest timestamp in python

Tags: python, string, timestamp, integer, bisect

I have a list of timestamps and a key timestamp to find the nearest one, both are in the format `'2019-11-22T11:37:52.338Z'`

I have tried this solution [Python - Locating the closest timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162379/python-locating-the-closest-timestamp) but since my timestamps are in `string` leads me with an error. When I tried to typecast them as shown below

```
def nearest(ts):
s = sorted(timestamp_list)
i = bisect_left(s, ts)
return min(s[max(0, i-1): i+2], key=lambda t: abs(int(ts) - int(t)))
```

ends up with `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2019-11-22T11:37:52.338Z'`

Any suggestions on how to overcome this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `strptime()` from the `datetime` module to convert your string to a datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime

ts = '2019-07-22T11:37:52.338Z'
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(ts, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

print(datetime_object)
```

Output:

```
2019-07-22 11:37:52.338000
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

---

And here the full example:

```py
from bisect import bisect_left
from datetime import datetime


ts_list_str = ['2010-11-22T11:37:52.338Z', '2018-11-22T11:37:52.338Z', '2017-11-22T11:37:52.338Z']
ts_list = [datetime.strptime(ts, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ') for ts in ts_list_str]

def nearest(ts):
    s = sorted(ts_list)
    i = bisect_left(s, ts)
    return min(s[max(0, i-1): i+2], key=lambda t: abs(ts - t))

ts_str = '2019-07-22T11:37:52.338Z'
ts = datetime.strptime(ts_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

print(nearest(ts))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. I was trying to get back to the original format for the nearest timestamp, which I further use it for comparison. I tried this `near_ts= near_ts.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]+('z')` But when I tried to compare this with the unchanged timestamp, it doesn't seem to work. I check the type of both the ts, and they seem to be the same `str`. Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

Comment: Ah okay, got it. Small mistake with 'z' instead of 'Z'.